# Handling UIIMagePickerController when compressing video screen appears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, uiimagepickercontroller, photo-gallery

I am using UIImagePicker for selecting video from library and trying to use the video in my application.For this I am using code like this

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

picker.delegate = self;
picker.mediaTypes=[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Now the problem is that  when any video is selected it shows compressing video message alongwith a progress bar.Meanwhile If I send my app in background I want to cancel this compression and dismismodalviewController so that corrupted compression does not occur.Is there any way to avoid this compression or to handle this so that result is either in success or in failure.Setting videoQuality is not solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the URL coming from `UIImagePickerControllerMediaType` was `nil`. The solution was getting the video URL from `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
            NSURL* url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
            //... read video with ALAssetsLibrary
}
```

Further info on how to read the video can be found here: [How to save video from assets url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568210/how-to-save-video-from-assets-url)