# How do I convert an assets URL into filesystem URL?

Tags: ios, swift

**TLDR; how to convert NSURL of form "assets-library://...." to "file:///...."**

In this scenario, the user takes a video in app and saves it to their images with the ALAssetsLibrary method `(writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum)`. From this method upon competion, I get an assetURL in the form `"assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=F60213D1-3C39-44A8-8D21-80587D1CF843&ext=mov"`.

I need to convert this asset URL to a file system url with format `file:///...` so that I can upload the file. (fileuploader requires file system NSURL of asset)

I've tried doing this to convert the asset URL into a filesystem URL but it doesn't work

```
writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL, completionBlock: { (assetURL:NSURL!, error:NSError!) }
......

let pathDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let filePath = "\(pathDocumentDirectory)/\(assetURL.lastPathComponent!)"
let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568210/how-to-save-video-from-assets-url

Comment: Is there any way to grab the existing file system URL without having to copy the entire avasset video to a new file and use that new filesystem URL? That's costly & takes time

Comment: You are using ALAssetsLibrary to get the video's from the device?

Comment: Yep, using ALAssetsLibrary to save the file to the device (good catch on the typo! I just need to grab the file system URL of that saved file for later use.

Comment: Does your problem got solved?

Comment: Yep, I ended up making a copy of the file and then grabbing the file URL from that.

Comment: Great Man :) Happy coding